# Both RAID hard discs are not readable in Windows

Tags: hard-drive, backup, raid, data-recovery, raid-1

I have a small network backup device that does mirror backup to two HDDs. Recently the backup stopped working. When I check the hard drives in a hard drive reader, Windows caanot read the drives and tells me to format them.

I don't know what filesystem my network backup device uses so I don't know if the HDDs are damaged or if Windows simply cannot read them. I also don't think it's likely that both discs are broken.

What can I do to diagnose my hard discs, and if possible, recover the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had been using an external raid storage system chances are that they are in ext3 or ext4 (linux), the most easy way to diagnose them is to download a linux image and put it on a usb stick, i can recommend [linux mint](https://www.linuxmint.com/download.php) or [ubuntu](https://www.ubuntu.com/desktop) but any will do it fine

if it is indeed a filesystem problem then you can try using a more advanced linux distribution like [kali](https://www.kali.org/), but be aware that you need command line to verify and repair them

https://linuxacademy.com/blog/linux/ntfs-partition-repair-and-recovery-in-linux/

Comment: You were basically right. The disc could be read using Linux after assembling it using `mdadm`..

Answer (score 0):

(Answering my own question)
The disc can be read using a Linux distribution. The disc uses a RAID filesystem which also cannot be read immediately. However, using `mdadm` it can.

I located the correct partition (`sdb6`) of the disk using GParted (`fdisk` should also work). I guessed it was this partition because it was by far the largest on the disc.

Then I assembled the RAID device (to `md1`) using `mdadm`:

```
mdadm -A -R /dev/md1 /dev/sdb6
```

I could then mount it normally using

```
mount /dev/md1 /media/backup
```